# can not open the file in java program

Tags: java

I need to open file but it give me an error in the main function
I'm trying to let the user but the file name if it is not correct the program will give an error message and terminate the program
Here is my program.

```
//import java.io.File;

//import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*; // file input/output

import java.io.IOException;

public class Stock{
String name;
String symbol;
double Price;

//Random randomNumbers = new Random();//Generate random numbers

  Stock(){ // no-argument constructor 
    name="";
    symbol="";
    Price=0.0;
  }

  Stock(String n,String s,double p){ //constructor with argument
    name=n;
    symbol=s;
    Price=p;
  }
  public void setname(String name){//mutators to set the value of name
     this.name=name;    
  }
  public void setsymbol(String symbol){//mutators to set the value of symbol 
        this.symbol=symbol; 
    }
  public void setnextPrice(double price){
        this.Price = price;     
    }
  public String getname(){//accessor to get the name

        return name;
    }

  public String getsymbol(){ //accessor to get the symbol
         return symbol;
    }
  public double getPrice(){//accessor to get currentPrice
        return Price;

    }


public void openfile()throws IOException{
    String f="";
    System.out.print("Please enter the file name: "+f);
    if (f.equals("stocks.txt")){
        Scanner x;
        x= new Scanner(new File("stocks.txt"));

        //PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

            String name = x.nextLine();

            System.out.println(name);

    }   
else{

    System.out.println("File Not Found");   
        return; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the main function
//import java.io.*; // file input/output
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.io.IOException;


public class StockList{
  Scanner input = null;

 public static void main(String [] arg){
  Stock stock=new Stock();
  Stock stock2=new Stock(name,symbol,pric);
  stock.openfile();
    
 }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code correctly. It looks like you are confusing `stock` and `stock2` in your main method.

Comment: All info relevant to solving this issue should be included in the question (and not down in the comment section). please edit your question, and do not hesitate to trim the bits of code that are not involved in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to read a file named stocks.txt and get it's contents line by line, you can do this in multiple ways

using Files API

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

List lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(uri),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());

iterate over this list and get content

using Scanner

```
        File file = new File("stock.txt");

        input = new Scanner(file);


        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
```

Using

```
    File file = new File("stocks.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        while (dis.available() != 0) {
            System.out.println(dis.readLine());
        }

    }
    catch (..) {}
```

you can use either one of way to achieve it, using Files API is easier way.

Comment: Thanks for the help
What if i want to get the highest price and the lowest price and calculate the average from the file?
Instead of getting line by line